# Monitoring SQL Server Bandwidth

Tags: sql-server, bandwidth, netmon

I think I can use NetMon to monitor traffic (b,kb,mb, gb) of my db (to/from) , however I dont know how to get a summary and breakdown of the traffic size.

Has anyone used Netmon for this and can either explain how or point me in the right direction.

Everything is local in my scenario , I just want to know the bandwidth usage of the db calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to find the bytes sent/received from a particular query, or the amount of bandwidth being used for all queries under a given load?

If you want to get an idea of the bytes sent/received for a single query, just turn on "Include client statistics" under the Query menu in SQL Management studio.

If you want to see the network utilization under a load, the easiest way would be to generate a load from another machine and then use perfmon on the DB server and add the counters for the Network Interface's bytes sent/received to monitor the actual utilization.

If you are limited to one machine then you might be able to try something that can isolate a single processes network traffic, like [netlimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/download.php)

Answer (score 0):

If your using SqlConnection from ADO.Net you can use the [provider statistics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h2ahss8.aspx) to get the total number of bytes received and sent.